# I want to render a specific static object in react native

Tags: react-native

I try to render a specific object inside a  component (static object) in react native,after i get it with http request from axios API .The (node)server works fine but whenever i try to render it on the screen nothing shows.

Also when i console.log the object its correct(on client side too) but still nothing on simulator screen.

I dont know if i do something wrong or i need hooks for that(im new in react native so excuse me if i open again some same question) .

The code is below :

**Client**

```
import React, { Component,
useEffect,
useState } from 'react';

import { 
StyleSheet, 
Text, 
View ,
} from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';

var res;

export default function App() {

   axios.get('http://x.x.x.x:x/rec')
  .then
   (function (response){
    console.log(response.data);
    res = response.data;
  })

  return (
  
    <View  style = {styles.container}>
        <Text>This car is a : {res}</Text>
    </View>

  
  )};
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1 ,
    marginTop:100,
  },

});
```

**Server**

```
const app = require('express')();
const { json } = require('body-parser');

const car = {
    type: "Fiat",
    model : "500"
  };

const myCar = JSON.stringify(car);



app.get("/rec",(req,res) => {
   res.send(myCar);
   console.log("Took Car");
})

app.get("/",(req,res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.send("You have done it ");
  console.log("Took /");
})



var listener = app.listen(8888,()=>{
  console.log(listener.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use hook for it

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
   const [label, setLabel] = useState('')
   
   axios.get('http://x.x.x.x:x/rec')
   .then((response) => {
     const data = response.data
     const resultLabel = typeof data === 'string' ? data : 
           `${data.type} ${data.model}`
     setLabel(`This car is a : ${resultLabel}`)
   })

  return (
    <View  style = {styles.container}>
        <Text>{label}</Text>
    </View>
  )};
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:100,
  },

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,it work also but for string .In object it shows me This car is : [object Object]

Comment: @ThanosRom can you describe your object structure? in general it calls to string method on your object and if you need something specific you need to prepare your data.

Comment: i need to import from server file the object car .I used JSON format to send it from server side to client side but when its time to render it shows [object Object].In string working but in json format its not.The object its on server side file that i posted in the start.

Comment: ok @ThanosRom you can do something like

```js
axios.get('http://x.x.x.x:x/rec')
.then((response) => {
const data = response.data
const resultLabel = typeof data === 'string' ? data : `${data.type} ${data.model}`
setLabel(`This car is a : ${resultLabel}`)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Finally it worked after days .Appreciate it ! :)